# How to prevent Apache / mod_rewrite from treating path as file with same name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp, mod-php

I'm using WAMP Server, mostly configured as-is out of the box.  I'm having trouble getting mod_rewrite to behave as expected locally (everything works fine on a production server).

I have a PHP file located at:
`/ajax/graphs/get-graph.php`

The way this file is normally invoked is via a bootstrap file loaded by
`/index.php`

I have a .htaccess file at the root with the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

So, basically, when my app requests via AJAX a call to `/ajax/graphs/get-graph/`it should be directed to `/index.php`.

The problem is, Apache/mod_rewrite sees the request path and loads `/ajax/graphs/get-graph.php` directly.

How do I prevent Apache from assuming that `/ajax/graphs/get-graph/` is a valid file because a php file of the same name exists at that location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've fallen into the trap of content negotiation ;-) As explained in [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#negotiation), there is an option called `MultiViews` which, when enabled, causes Apache to basically convert nonexistent directory names into their corresponding filenames.

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for `/some/dir/foo`, if `/some/dir` has MultiViews enabled, and `/some/dir/foo` does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named `foo.*`, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files...

The intent is that you can have several versions of a file in different formats or languages, like

```
/some/dir
- foo.en.gif
- foo.en.png
- foo.en.jpg
- foo.fr.gif
- foo.fr.png
- foo.fr.jpg
```

and Apache will choose the best one based on the preferences provided by the browser.

To fix it, all you should need to do is add the directive

```
Options -MultiViews
```

in a `<Directory>` or `<Location>` block corresponding to `/ajax/graphs`. Or, if you don't have access to the main server configuration, you can put it in `/ajax/graphs/.htaccess`.

Comment: Worked like a champ!  Thanks!